# Convergent pointwise does not show convergent in max-distance?

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, metric-spaces

Let $(x_n)_{n=1}^{\infty}$ be a sequence in $c_{00}$, for every $n \ge 1$ we denote $x_n = (x_n^{(1)},\ldots,x_n^{(k)},\ldots)$. Let $x = (x^{(1)},\ldots,x^{(k)}\ldots)$ be a vector in $c_{00}$.

If it is true that 
$lim_{n \to \infty}x_n^{(k)} = x^{(k)}$ (Convergence in $\mathbb{R}$), $\forall k \ge 1$.

Then we say that the sequence $(x_n)_{n=1}^{\infty}$ converges componentwise to $x$

Give a example that $(x_n)_{n=1}^\infty$ converges to $x$ componentwise does not imply that $(x_n)_{n=1}^\infty$ converges to $x$ in $||\cdot||_\infty$.

Can someone give me help? I tried but cannot convince myself such example exists...

Comment: what is the spaces $c_{00}$ ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $x_n=1$ and other components are equal to zero.  Then the sequence converges componentwise, but not in the infinity norm.